# Save message properties only locally (Outlook)

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in, exchange-server, mapi

How can an Outlook add-in set a MAPI property (for example, the body content) on a message, but only have it saved in the local cache (and not sent back to the exchange server)?  I've seen this done with a few encryption add-ins.

I'm open to using pretty much any API that could do the trick.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in this as well.  I haven't found a way to prevent it from getting changes sent back to the server.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? Any pointers would definitely help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So I discovered this in MSDN.  [How to: Manage a Message in an OST Without Invoking a Synchronization in Cached Exchange Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb820960%28office.12%29.aspx)  Stephen Griffin first talked about this back in 2005 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2005/10/31/487416.aspx).

I haven't had a chance to test it yet, but it does look like you can modify the OST and not trigger a synchronization.  The trick is requesting the message using IID_IMessageRaw and not IID_IMessage, like would normally be done.

The only issue you might run into is that it appears to require using Extended MAPI and hence C++.  The tags on the question list VSTO, so I'm not sure what the requirements might still be.

The example provided is:

```
HRESULT HrOpenRawMessage (
    LPMDB lpMSB, 
    ULONG cbEntryID, 
    LPENTRYID lpEntryID, 
    ULONG ulFlags, 
    LPMESSAGE* lpMessage)
{
    ULONG ulObjType = NULL;

    HRESULT hRes = lpMDB->OpenEntry(
        cbEntryID,
        lpEntryID,
        IID_IMessageRaw,
        ulFlags,
        &ulObjType,
        (LPUNKNOWN*) lpMessage));

   return hRes;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting find!  Using extended MAPI is perfectly fine for our application - in fact we are already using it.  Thanks Joe, this may be very helpful if it works how it sounds.  I will try to test this next week and let you know how it goes.